# 2D array get row and column by a position number from 0 to size of the array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

For example, I have a 2d Array set up like this:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+ 
|   |   |   |   |   | 
|0  |1  |2  |3  |4  | 
+---+---+---+---+---+ 
|   |   |   |   |   | 
|5  |6  |7  |8  |9  | 
+---+---+---+---+---+ 
|   |   |   |   |   | 
|10 |11 |12 |13 |14 | 
+---+---+---+---+---+ 
|   |   |OOO|   |   | 
|15 |16 |OOO|18 |19 | 
+---+---+---+---+---+ 
|   |   |   |   |   | 
|20 |21 |22 |23 |24 | 
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

where the o's are what I placed at spot 17. However, I was actually trying to place the o's at spot 7. I'm taking user input of one of these numbers to do it.

To get the values of the row and column, I'm using

```
int row = Math.floorDiv(size*size - 1, space);
int col = space % size;
```

where `size` is the length of the row/column (in this case it's 5, it's always a square array) and `space` is the number of the "cell" that I'm trying to place the o's into.

I know that the column function works correctly, but I can't seem to figure out how to calculate the row.

---

EDIT: Thanks to Cinnam and Nayuki Minase; the answer is just `space / size`. So instead, I'll ask a different question that I also am not sure to overcome. When placing pieces, I have to check that the spaces to the north, west, east, and south of it are not occupied by a different player. For this, I'm using the code

```
    if((board[row][col+1] == otherPlayerInt) 
            || (board[row][col-1] == otherPlayerInt) 
            || (board[row+1][col] ==  otherPlayerInt) 
            || (board[row][col-1]==otherPlayerInt)){ 
        return false;
    }
```

Where the other player is represented by a negative integer. If I do this though, and the piece is placed on the edge, I will get an ArrayOutOfBoundsException. What are some ways I can overcome this?

Comment: Can't you just do `row = space / size`?

Comment: -_- wow that was painfully obvioius wasn't it

Comment: That can happen, no worries :)

Comment: Yeah, I realized that and I was just about to post a new question but I have to wait 90 minutes. I'll post a new question within the hour and link it here if you want to send your answer over there.

Comment: The last `board[row][col-1]` should be `board[row-1][col]`. To avoid the bounds error, you simply have to check if you are at the edge. Or if `board[row][col]` never equals `otherPlayerInt`, you could replace `[row+1]` with `[Math.min(row+1, size-1)]` and `[row-1]` with `[Math.max(row-1, 0)]`. Same with `col`.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I'm using another if statement to check that the spot is empty before placing anything into it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A concise answer:

```
int row = space / size;
int col = space % size;
```

And the inverse operation:

```
int index = row * size + col;
```